# How compile this fork of WebRTC for iOS

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, webrtc

I need to compile this fork of WebRTC for iOS
https://github.com/pixiv/webrtc

I have followed the steps indicated here: https://github.com/pixiv/webrtc/releases.

but when i try to build the framework using python build_ios_libs.py --bitcode

it shows and error find_depot_tools file not found

I have cloned the repo to my computer with this command line;
gh repo clone pixiv/webrtc

please help am i doing right or missing something??
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need [google depot tools](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git)
`git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git`

and set the path to the tools
`export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/depot_tools/`